# MVC Chart just displaying text stream

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, charts

I am trying to put some sort of dashboarding into my MVC application and I cannot get it to render the chart correctly. It just seems to display the byte-stream rather than an image.

On my main *Index* page I have a button that will post back to the controller to acquire the data (sample data in this example) and then update the results section.

**DataPoint.cs**

```
public class DataPoint
{
    public DateTime DateMark { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<ChartTest.Models.DataPoint>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Generate", new AjaxOptions() { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "results" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-danger">
                <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: #80929C; color: #F6E0C7">
                    <div class="row">

                        <!-- Stuff to get user request information removed -->

                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12" style="vertical-align: bottom">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Generate" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-group" style="background-color: transparent; border: none; margin-top: 20px">
            <div class="panel panel-danger" style="background-color: transparent; border: none">
                <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: #80929C; color: #F6E0C7">

                    <div id="results">

<!-- RESULTS WILL BE PLACED HERE WHEN BUTTON PRESSED -->

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**Chart.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<ChartTest.Models.DataPoint>

@{
    var key = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
                      .AddTitle("My Data")
                      .AddSeries("Default",
                                 xValue: Model, xField: "DateMark",
                                 yValues: Model, yFields: "Count")
                      .Write();
}
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Generate()
    {
        List<Models.DataPoint> results = new List<Models.DataPoint>();

        //
        // Go get the data here and add to the `results` list
        //

        return PartialView("Chart", results);
    }
}
```

Here's what gets rendered

[image]

Comment: Your `Chart.cshtml` doesn't actually have any output? As in, you assign to a variable but do nothing with it. Where does the template actually write your HTML?

Comment: If I take the contents of the `chart.cshtml` and put it in the main index page where the results are rendered by the ajax postback, then a chart replaces the entire page (it's just a plain white page with the chart, the menu gone, the "button bar" nothing) - So I know that chart renders something...

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `Chart` is not part of MVC but Web Pages. They won't just easily merge as the chart is just writing raw image data to your view.

[This article by Scott Mitchell](https://web.archive.org/web/20201205223757/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092210-1.aspx) gives a guide on how to integrate Web Pages elements into your MVC project.

You basically have to wrap the Chart view inside another action, which you then insert into a view containing just an image tag

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetChart")" />
```